# too many links in /var/lib/docker error while building Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to run `docker-compose build` and getting the following error:

> ERROR: ...
>   evalSymlinksInScope: too many links in
>   /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a476d12eaac1c1e3cc684c992cf829b61b999959fd7d23d5a27120dbfd43e178/merged/opt/api/resources

I searched online and have tried running the following commands, but nothing works:

```
docker network prune
docker images prune
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

If I run `ln -ls /var/lib`, there is nothing in this folder about `/docker`. Is this referring to the Docker container? If so, how can this be, when I am in the process of building it. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be great, thank you.

Comment: should go on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok, thanks @MichałKrzysztofFeiler, posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553950/too-many-links-in-var-lib-docker-error-while-building-docker-container