# How can I Fix 'WORKDIR /code' Error in Flask Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got this code from [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
# Install app dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Bundle app source
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

I am getting this error

```
 > [2/6] WORKDIR /code:
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM python:3.11-alpine
   2 |
   3 | >>> WORKDIR /code
   4 |     ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
   5 |     ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/kl5w9si1xv311f5b73j521acw/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

Here are the project files

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIDdU.png)

I wanted to successfully create the Dockerfile executable for others

Comment: Does this solve your issue? Follow through to the StackExchange answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024392/too-many-links-in-var-lib-docker-error-while-building-docker-container

Comment: nah I went through it , but I appreciate the effort @opeonikute

Comment: I follow the `gettingstarted` steps, with no error, and run well on Windows 11.  Did you try it first without your project files?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help guys , I figured it out. Seems like insteada the making the code more complex, all I had to do was to simplify it